# Scala Parallel Seq not confroming to Seq

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I'm relatively new to Scala but I think I understand its type system and parallel collections and I can't understand this error:

I have a function

```
def myFun(a : Seq[MyType], b : OtherType) : Seq[MyType] = {
    val parA = a.par
    def update(q : OtherType)(x : MyType) : MyType = x.updated(q)
    parA.map(update(b))
```

I get an error that says

```
Error:(63, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq[MyType]
 required: Seq[MyType]
    parA.map(update(b))
                 ^
```

If `ParSeq` is a subtype of `Seq` then why doesn't this work?

(As I was writing this I realized that to fix it I can call the `.seq` method on the result, but why do I have to? and what's the difference between .toSeq which the IDE tells me is redundant and `.seq` which seems to have worked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If `ParSeq` is a sub-type of `Seq` then why doesn't this work?

It isn't. `ParSeq` is a sub-type of `GenSeq`, which is not the same thing. The difference is that when you have a `Seq`, you expect all operations to happen in sequence, but with `ParSeq`, that is not necessarily the case!

If I have:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) foreach println
```

I expect the elements to be printed in the order they are presented every time. `ParSeq` cannot guarantee that:

```
scala> ParSeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) foreach println
2
1
3
4
5
```

Therefore, if I were expecting a `Seq`, and instead got a `ParSeq` that had the above behavior, that could cause some nasty bugs. If you don't care about that and can handle both situations, ask for a `GenSeq`.

Comment: I totally understand the answer but in Scala library 2.11.8 we have the following: 

`trait ParSeq[+T]
extends scala.collection/*.immutable*/.GenSeq[T]
   with scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq[T]
   with ParIterable[T]
   with GenericParTemplate[T, ParSeq]
   with ParSeqLike[T, ParSeq[T], scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T]]
{
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[ParSeq] with GenericParCompanion[ParSeq] = ParSeq
  override def toSeq: ParSeq[T] = this
}`

so ParSeq mixes in Seq. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @longliveenduro `Seq` is one of the type parameters in the `ParSeqLike` mixin, but `ParSeq` does not mix it in directly.

Answer (score 9):

I'm lookiing at the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq) and can't see where it says ParSeq extends Seq, am I missing something?

Also as for the second part of the question:
toSeq returns a ParSeq and seq returns a Seq.
To be clear:

```
val x: ParSeq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3).par
val y: ParSeq[Int] = x.toSeq
val z: Seq[Int] = x.seq
```

Since the .toSeq doesn't 'do anything' your IDE is saying its redundant.

Comment: Ok I see the toSeq vs seq. And I guess I misunderstood the difference between GenSeq and Seq. But the docs do say "Parallel sequences inherit the Seq trait" so I'm still confused

Comment: First line.... I missed that. I think that's a mistake in the docs and its meant to say "Parallel sequences inherit the GenSeq trait". m-z's answers show why ParSeq cannot extend Seq